# KDE KIO caches all network media before viewing

Tags: networking, kde, cache, media

What is kioexec? Why does it run every time I try and open a picture or video?  It appears to copy the entire file to ~/.cache before viewing.  Same happens w/ VLC and other media applications as well. This is super slow for large and medium format RAW DSLR photos and full length movies.

Thanks,
o8ko8k

System info:

Desktop HW
intel-i7
32GB ram
500gb SSD HDD
AC1700 WIFI

OS:

```
cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```